# Language encoding and displaying issues on my server

Tags: database, unicode, utf-8, http-headers, arabic

My app has arabic content in it. And everything was working fine on my development environment (localhost XAMPP). Now I moved to a Windows 2008 Server with Plesk, and the Arabic content is not displayed. Instead I get question marks ?????. I checked the database, and I can see the Arabic content in it, and I made sure that the database stores UTF-8. What reasons could cause that? I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What did you make your app with? PHP, Perl, Python, .. What database do you use? MySQL, SQL Server, ...